# Why does my observer doesn't get notified when a new item is added to my livedata list

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I need to get an Observer event when the item is added to the List of LiveData.

```
// mutable live data list of shoes
private var _shoesList =  MutableLiveData<List<Shoe>>()
val shoesList: LiveData<List<Shoe>>
    get() = _shoesList
```

When I add a new item to the list

```
_shoesList.value?.plus(Shoe(name,sizeDouble,company,description))
        _shoesList.value = _shoesList.value // so the observer gets notified
```

The observer code:

```
 val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
```

The code inside the observer block is never reached

```
viewModel.shoesList.observe( viewLifecycleOwner , Observer { newShoe ->

                Log.i("ShoeListFragment","i am inside the observer block")

        })
```

I am still a beginner so any help would be apprciated :)

Answer (score 1):

[`plus`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus.html) *returns a new list* which is the original list with your new `Shoe` added to it - it doesn't affect the original list. [`plusAssign`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus-assign.html) *adds to the original*.

Those are both `operator` functions (see the `operator` keyword) which means you can use them like:

```
// plus
shoesList + newShoe

// plusAssign
shoesList += newShoe
```

If you're not familiar with `+=`, the longer version is `shoesList = shoesList + newShoe`. So you can tell you're reassigning the value of `shoesList` with that one. Just doing `shoesList + newShoe` doesn't change anything - you just combine them and then do nothing with the result.

**But** your `LiveData` holds an immutable `List` type, not a `MutableList` - so you can't add to that. You can't use `plusAssign` here, you need to use `plus` to create a *new* list (the original combined with the new element) and then assign it to your `LiveData`:

```
// store the result of your plus call
val newShoes = _shoesList.value?.plus(Shoe(name,sizeDouble,company,description))
_shoesList.value = newShoes // you need to assign the new list anyway!
```

So not much of a change from what you already had, but hopefully that gives you a better idea of what's going on! If you *were* using a `MutableList`, you could just do *plusAssign*, but yeah you'd have to reassign the `value` to nudge it into updating its observers.

And honestly, creating a new list is usually safer, because you're not modifying the original one, which other things might have stored a reference to. For example, if you're using a `DiffUtil` in a `RecyclerView`, which compares the *old* list to a *new* one... if you *change* the old one and then push that as the new one, the `DiffUtil` is looking at two references to the same object. So there's no difference, meaning it doesn't trigger an update (the old list *did* change, but all it can do is compare to the new one, which is the same list). You can get other bugs changing old data in the background like that, while outwardly pushing a "new" value

Comment: Thanks for your help and explaination ,but unfortunatley the observer still doesnot get notified.

Comment: @AdhamAhmad if you set `value` that should trigger a push to all your observers (even if it's literally the same value, unless you've called `distinctUntilChanged()` on your `LiveData` to get a new one that ignores updates with the same values). Your list wasn't changing in your example, so that *was* a problem, but it sounds like you have a different problem with your observer. Either set a breakpoint in there and debug it, see what's going on, or at least log a message when the observer's function is run - check if it's firing (it should be), and maybe the new value's not being handled right

Answer (score 1):

`MutableLiveData` contains a list of shoes, you need to declare them separately in your view model:

```
private var _shoes = mutableListOf<Shoe>()
private var _shoesList =  MutableLiveData<List<Shoe>>(_shoes)
```

And expose `LiveData` to anyone who wants to listen to data changes:

```
val shoesList: LiveData<List<Shoe>>
        get() = _shoesList
```

whenever you want to add a new `Shoe`, just add it in the `_shoes` list

```
_show.add(new Shoe(..))
```

And then update the mutableLiveData to notify listener :

```
//notify observers
_shoesList.postValue(_shoes)
```

`_shoes` is a private variable, add this method to be able to add a new `shoe`:

```
fun add(shoe: Shoe) = viewModelScope.launch {
    _shoes.add(shoe)

    //notify observer
    _shoesList.postValue(_shoes)
}
```

Here is the complete code :

```
class ShoeViewModel() : ViewModel() {

    private var _shoes = mutableListOf<Shoe>()
    private var _shoesList =  MutableLiveData<List<Shoe>>(_shoes)

    val shoesList: LiveData<List<Shoe>>
        get() = _shoesList

    fun add(shoe: Shoe) = viewModelScope.launch {
        _shoes.add(shoe)

        //notify observer
        _shoesList.postValue(_shoes)
    }
}
```

call this line of code, every time you want to add a new shoe

```
viewModel.add(new Shoe(...))
```